# $refs is undefined - Custom File Input button referencing issue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a list series of cards based on vehicle data and associated images. I would like to add a custom upload image button to each card but there is a referencing issue.

Using the standard input type file, if I choose **Browse** from the input then it works:

```
<v-col v-for="item in vehicles" :key="item.id">
    <v-card class="mx-auto" outlined>
        <input 
            type="file"
            @change="uploadImage"
            accept="image/*"
            :ref="`imageInput${item.id}`"
        >
    </v-card>
</v-col>
```

However I would like to use a custom button. If I hide the Input and add a button using:

```
        <input 
            type="file"
            @change="uploadImage"
            accept="image/*"
            :ref="`imageInput${item.id}`"
            class="d-none"
        >

       <v-btn @click="$refs.imageInput[item.id].click()">Upload photo</v-btn>
```

and click the v-btn I get an error since I am not referencing it correctly. Any pointers as to how this should be done?

Using methods:

```
<v-btn @click="buttonClicked(item.id)">Upload photo</v-btn>

methods:{
    buttonClicked(itemId) {
        let ref = `imageInput${itemId}`
        console.log('ref: ', ref)
        let element = this.$refs[ref]
        console.log('element', element)
        element.click()
    }
```

I get the error:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: element.click is not a function"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ref will output a string like this, when item id is 4

```
imageInput4
```

In your `v-btn` you are trying to access the item by index, where it should rather look like this

```
$refs[`imageInput${item.id}`]
```

However I suggest moving that call to a method, this way it will be easy to debug

```
buttonClicked(itemId) {
    let ref = `imageInput${itemId}`
    console.log('ref: ', ref)
    let element = this.$refs[ref]
    console.log('element', element)
    element.click()
}
```

Comment: I am afraid neither works: 1) _vm.$refs[("imageInput" + item.id)].click is not a function2) Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: element.click is not a function"

Comment: @RGriffiths Please post the error you are seeing. I recreated this locally and it works

Comment: Are you suggesting $refs[`imageInput${item.id}`].click()

Comment: @RGriffiths `@click="$refs[\`imageInput${item.id}\`].click()"`

Comment: If I use element[0].click() - the returned element is an array - it seems to work. Thanks. It is a shame it doesn't want to work with describing a method. Seems a bit clunky to me, but I am new to Vue and just learning the ropes. Thanks again